# JSF 2.3: "Array index out of range" when rendering a form with Url containing ''&&"

Tags: url, websphere-liberty, rerender, jsf-2.3

Given a url with params such that:

```
page.xhtml?param1=value&&param2=value
```

It appears that after submitting a form on that page, the following exception and stack trace occurs:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.encodeURL(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:906)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.encodeActionURL(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:364)
    at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.encodeActionURL(ExternalContextWrapper.java:80)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlFormRendererBase.encodeBegin(HtmlFormRendererBase.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:597)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:527)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:551)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:551)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1897)
```

It appears that this will happen when the form is being re-rendered.

Using ajax to narrow what is being re-rendered allows me to side step the issue.

**With that said, I'm wondering if there are more options to fixing this issue?**

Using IBM's Liberty 18.0.0.3, IBM's JSF 2.3 [1.0.0]

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Can you provide a small app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this issue is unique to my project's configurations.  After some selective removals and additions it was discovered that a view-handler responsible for re-attaching request params back onto the url was the culprit.

The param string

```
param1=value&&param2=value
```

Would be reattached as

```
=&param1=value&param2=value
```

Which in turn caused the encoding exception.

Thank you and Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

That version of WebSphere Liberty is almost 3 years old, so I would first recommend moving up to a recent version of [WebSphere Liberty](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6250961) (or [Open Liberty](https://openliberty.io/downloads/#runtime_releases)) and checking if the issue has since been resolved.

With Liberty's zero migration architecture, the move to the latest version should be pretty seamless.... and not only will you get ~3 years worth of bug & security fixes but also performance and development enhancements.